On the number of f-stable subsets
Let $\ f: X \to X \ $  be a function defined on set $X$ of cardinality $n$.
Let $\mathscr{I}(f) =  $ { $ A \subseteq X : f(A) \subseteq A $ } be the f-stable subsets of X.
What can be said about #$\mathscr{I}(f)$?
Let #$\mathscr{I}(f)=I(f)$, let's call it the invariance of f, obviously we have that, if $f=\text{id}_X $ then $I(f)=2^n$. Let's exclude this case. It can then be proved that necessarily $I(f)\leq\frac{3}{4}2^n$.
proof. If $f\neq\text{id}_X$ then it must exist an element $x$ s.t. $f(x)\neq x$, let $y=f(x)$, then every subset $A \subseteq X$ s.t. $x \in A$ and $y \notin A$ isn't f-stable. There are $2^{n-2}$ subsets containing $x$ but not its image, therefore $I(f)\leq 2^n-2^{n-2}=3\cdot2^{n-2}=\frac{3}{4}2^n$
First question: Is there some other value that $I(f)$ cannot have, or for every $k$ s.t. $ 2\leq k \leq \frac{3}{4}2^n$ there is a function $f$ s.t. $I(f)=k$? and if so, is there a constructive way to define that function?
A simple but interesting fact is the following: if it is possible to partition the set $X$ into two f-stable subsets $A$ and $B$, then $I(f)=I(f|_A) \cdot I(f|_B)$, (here there is a small abuse of notation, by $I(f|_A)$ we mean the $f|_A$-stable subsets of $A$). So, so if we see $X$ as the union of a set $A$ and a set $B$, such that #$A=a$ and #$B=b$ with $a+b=n$, if we can construct a function $\alpha:A \to A$ and a function $\beta:B \to B$ with $I(A)=p$ and $I(B)=q$, then then we are able to define a function $f: X \to X$ such that $f|_A=\alpha$ and $f|_B=\beta$, and we will have $I(f)=p \cdot q$.
This fact gave me the idea to try to answer the question using a proof by induction. The base case is obvious, let's consider the inductive step $n-1\ \to n$. By inductive hypothesis we are able, for every k between $2$ and $\frac{3}{4}2^{n-1}$, to define a function $g: Y \to Y$ such that $I(g)=k$, now if we add an element $x$ to the set, thus arriving at cardinality $n$, we can define a function $f$ such that $f$ is equal to $g$ on the first $n-1$ elements, and $f(x)=x$. We have that $X=Y \cup ${$x$}, and by the fact mentioned above we have that $I(f)=I(g) \cdot 2$. This allows us to show that, in case $n$, we can obtain any even invariance between $\frac{3}{4}2^{n-1}$ and $\frac{3}{4}2^n$, and it also gives us a constructive method for doing so, but it does not include the odd case.
Edit: as Qiaochu Yuan noted, this proof by induction does not work, because the result is weaker than the inductive hypothesis. At most it can be used to double a given invariance by adding a fixed point.
Second question: Fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, what is the minimum $n$ such that there exists a set $X$ and a function $f: X \to X$ such that $I(f)=k$?
Let $\gamma(k)=\min${$n \in \mathbb{N} | \exists f: X \to X, I(f)=k$}, if the answer to the first question is yes, then we can answer the second, it is sufficient to look for the minimum $n$ such that $\frac{3}{4}2^n \geq k$ (unless $k$ is a power of $2$, in which case just calculate $\log_2{k}$, and $f$ would be an identity function over $\log_2{k}$ elements). So in this case, we would have that $n \geq \log_2({\frac{4}{3} \cdot k})$. So, we would have $\gamma(k)= \lceil \log_2({\frac{4}{3} \cdot k}) \rceil$. Another interesting idea would be to write $k$ as $a \cdot b$, and work on $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$, it is true that $\gamma(k)=\gamma(a)+\gamma(b)$?
Any ideas/suggestions regarding this topic?

Your induction in the 4th-to-last paragraph does not work. You assume as the inductive hypothesis the strong claim that you can get every $k$ between $2$ and $\frac{3}{4} 2^{n-1}$ (which I don't believe is true) but you end up proving something much weaker so it is not an induction.

You're right, it's more of a failed proof by induction, I was trying to complete it by somehow getting the odd numbers too (maybe finding some clever way to map the new element) but I couldn't (and maybe it's impossible). The only thing that attempt at induction actually proves is that I can double the invariance by adding a fixed point. Thanks for the correction, I'll include it in the main post!

See my answer, we can get the odd numbers pretty easily!

Edit #4: Surprisingly A117498 has appeared exactly once before on this site, here! Also I have submitted a comment to the OEIS page noting this connection.
Edit #3: Okay, here is a short very sketchy discussion of the relationship between this sequence and the other similar sequences in the OEIS, just to have it written down somewhere. This won't make sense until you read the rest of the answer first. Also I will include a nice picture.

A003313, "Length of shortest addition chain for $n$," agrees up until term $23$; the $I$-recursion can be used to show that a function $f$ on an $n$-element set satisfying $I(f) = k$ corresponds to a way to construct $k$ by starting with the number $2$ and repeatedly either multiplying two previously constructed numbers or adding $1$, in such a way that the number of $1$s and $2$s used is $n$. So $\gamma(k) = n$ means that $n$ is the smallest number of $1$s and $2$s in such a representation. For example, $15 = (1 + 2)(1 + 2 \cdot 2)$ corresponds to $\gamma(15) = 5$. These constructions correspond to certain special addition chains, namely combinations of the "binary method" and the "factor method." So A003313 is a lower bound. (Using only the "binary method" corresponds to the logarithmic upper bound in terms of the binary digits below.)

A064097, "A quasi-logarithm defined inductively by $a(1) = 0$ and $a(p) = 1 + a(p-1)$ if $p$ is prime and $a(nm) = a(n) + a(m)$ if $m,n > 1$," agrees up until term $33$; this corresponds to always choosing the second case in the $\gamma$-recursion whenever possible, which is often a good idea but not optimal.  For the first disagreement $\gamma(33) = 6$ it is actually optimal to subtract $1$ since $32 = 2^5$, giving $33 = 1 + 2^5$, whereas the quasi-logarithm corresponds to always factoring, giving $33 = (1 + 2)(1 + 2(1 + 2 \cdot 2))$. So A064097 is an upper bound.

A137813, "Minimal number of points needed to make a topology having n open sets," agrees up until term $23$: if $f : X \to X$ is a function on a finite set then the collection of $f$-stable subsets is closed under union and intersection, making it a finite topology on $X$! So A137813 is a lower bound. Some of the ideas in the analysis below can be rephrased in topological terms; for example the basins are literally the connected components in the topological sense, collapsing cycles corresponds to taking the $T_0$ quotient, and periodic points are the generic points of their basins.


Also there is a nice way to simultaneously draw the graph of a cycle-free function $f : X \to X$ and show that it satisfies $I(f) = k$ (so that if $|X| = n$ then you've shown that $\gamma(k) \le n$). We can draw the functional graph, then label every vertex by the number of stable subsets of the tree "above" it. This lets you visualize the $I$-recursion in a nice way. Here's an example I chose that has some nice symmetry showing that $\gamma(626) \le 13$, corresponding to the decomposition $626 = 1 + (1 + 2 \cdot 2)^5$:

(The notational convention is that there's no arrow pointing out from $626$ because it's a fixed point. This makes it as easy as possible to describe the $I$-recursion graphically because you just delete the fixed point and it automatically creates the correct new fixed points.)

Edit: I computed the first $33$ values of $\gamma(k)$ and searched them on the OEIS. This sequence is A117498. There were surprisingly many other sequences that agreed up to a smaller number of terms; $\gamma(23) = 7$ rules out A003313 (which is a lower bound) and A137813 (also a lower bound), and $\gamma(33) = 6$ rules out A064097 (which is an upper bound).
A117498 appears to be somewhat obscure but it was mentioned on the arXiv here and here, and on codegolf here.

Edit #2: Here is a general discussion. There's an analogue of cycle decomposition for arbitrary functions $f : X \to X$ on a finite set, not necessarily invertible, which I don't know a name for but which I am going to call the cycle-tree decomposition. It goes like this: draw the discrete dynamical system $(X, f)$ as a directed graph with vertex set $X$ and directed edges of the form $x \to f(x)$. The graphs we get are exactly the directed graphs in which every vertex has outdegree exactly $1$, which apparently are known as directed pseudoforests or functional graphs. What do these look like?
First, if we take $x \in X$ and keep iterating it, producing the orbit $\{ x, f(x), f^2(x), \dots \}$, the sequence must eventually be periodic. The periodic points are the cycles in the cycle-tree decomposition; the union of all cycles of $f$ is its eventual image $\text{im}^{\infty}(f)$.
Given a cycle $C$ we can consider its basin of attraction $f^{-\infty}(C)$, which is the set of all points $x \in X$ such that the orbit of $f$ eventually hits the cycle. The action of $f$ partitions $X$ into a disjoint union of these basins; these are the "connected components." The basin of attraction can be further partitioned into subsets $f^{-\infty}(c), c \in C$ consisting of the points $x \in f^{-\infty}(C)$ which hit the point $c$ first. These subsets are all rooted trees with root $c$, directed so that all edges point towards $c$; these are the trees in the cycle-tree decomposition. So, every point is either in a cycle or in a tree.

 You can think of the cycle-tree decomposition as the "set analogue" of Jordan normal form, where the cycles are like eigenvectors (so permutations are analogous to diagonalizable linear maps here, not invertible ones) and the trees are like generalized eigenvectors.

So arbitrary functional graphs are given by starting with a collection of cycles, then rooting a tree to each point in the cycles, with edges directed towards the roots. It is criminal to discuss this without a picture, so here is one, from Tom Leinster:


Theorem: $I(f)$ can be computed as follows.

If $f_1, \dots f_k$ denote the restrictions of $f : X \to X$ to its basins, then $I(f) = I(f_1) I(f_2) \dots I(f_k)$.
If $[f]$ denotes the function obtained from $f$ by collapsing each cycle of $f$ to a point, then $I([f]) = I(f)$.
If $f$ has a single periodic point $p$ (which is necessarily fixed), then consider the function $f \setminus p$ obtained by removing $p$ and making all points in $f^{-1}(p)$ fixed points. Then $I(f) = I(f \setminus p) + 1$.


Sketch. (I haven't been as clear in the following as I could be so let me know if any points need clarifying.)

This follows from the fact that the basins are a partition of $X$ into $f$-stable subsets. As you've observed, since the different basins don't interact, an $f$-stable subset of $X$ is exactly a tuple of $f$-stable subsets of each basin.

Every $f$-stable subset either contains a given cycle $C$ or is disjoint from it. It contains a given cycle $C$ iff it contains any point in the basin $f^{-\infty}(C)$ of $C$, and the $f$-stability condition does not change if we collapse $C$ to a point (in the sense that it is the same condition on $f^{-\infty}(C) \setminus C$), so is a bijection from $f$-stable subsets to $[f]$-stable subsets.

Removing $p$ is a bijection from $f$-stable subsets containing $p$ to $f \setminus p$-stable subsets. There is one additional $f$-stable subset, which is the empty set. $\Box$


This gives a recursion (let's call it the $I$-recursion) which computes $I(f)$ by breaking $f$ up into basins, collapsing its cycles to fixed points, deleting these points, then recursing (after the first step we don't need to collapse cycles). The precise form of this recursion also determines a recursion for $\gamma(k)$ (the minimum size of a set $X$ with a function $f : X \to X$ satisfying $I(f) = k$):

Corollary: $\gamma(k)$ is defined by the base case $\gamma(1) = 0$ and the recursion
$$\gamma(k) = \min \left( \gamma(k-1) + 1, \min_{ab=k, 1 < a, b < k} \gamma(a) + \gamma(b) \right).$$

This is exactly the recursion satisfied by A117498.
Sketch. The base case $\gamma(1) = 0$ comes from taking $X$ to be empty and $f : X \to X$ to be the empty function. In general, let $\gamma(k) = n$ and let $f : X \to X$ be a minimal function (so $|X| = n$) satisfying $I(f) = k$. Then we have two cases.

Case 1: $f$ has multiple basins $f_1, \dots f_i$, in which case $I(f) = I(f_1) \dots I(f_i)$. Each of the $f_i$ must also be a minimal function taking on its $I$-value, or else we could replace it with a smaller function without changing the $I$-value of $f$, which would contradict the minimality of $f$. This means $\gamma(k) = \gamma(I(f_1)) + \dots + \gamma(I(f_i))$, and corresponds to the second case of the minimization above.

Case 2: $f$ is a single basin. Since collapsing cycles doesn't change the value of $I$ and $f$ is minimal, $f$ must be cycle-free, so $f$ has a single periodic point $p$, which gives $I(f) = I(f \setminus p) + 1$. Again, $f \setminus p$ must be minimal, or else we could replace it with a smaller function (and perform the inverse of the $f \mapsto f \setminus p$ construction, where we add $p$ and direct all the old fixed points to it), which would contradict the minimality of $f$. This gives $\gamma(k) = \gamma(k-1) + 1$ and is the first case of the minimization above. $\Box$


Let's call this the $\gamma$-recursion. The following are easy corollaries.

If $p$ is prime, then $\gamma(p) = \gamma(p-1) + 1$. In particular, $\gamma(2) = 1, \gamma(3) = 2$.
$\gamma(2k) \le \gamma(k) + 1$ and $\gamma(2k+1) \le \gamma(k) + 2$.
By 3, if $d_0(k)$ denotes the number of $0$s in the binary expansion of $k$ and $d_1(k)$ denotes the number of $1$s, then $\boxed{ \gamma(k) \le 2 d_0(k) + d_1(k) - 2 \le 2 \lceil \log_2 k \rceil - 1 }$. So $\gamma(k)$ is logarithmically bounded.
$\gamma(3k) \le \gamma(k) + 2$ and $\gamma(3k+1) \le \gamma(k) + 3$. This can be used to show that the bound from 4 is not sharp.

For provably calculating small values of $\gamma$ it is also useful to have lower bounds. The easy "information-theoretic" lower bound that comes from a set of size $n$ having $2^n$ subsets gives:

$\gamma(k) \ge \lceil \log_2 k \rceil$.

This gives $\gamma(2^i) = i$ (which is clear from the definition but it's nice to note it here since it doesn't immediately follow from the $\gamma$-recursion). And your argument in the 4th paragraph gives:

If $k \neq 2^i$, then $\gamma(k) \ge \lceil \log_2 \frac{4}{3} k \ \rceil$.

This gives $\gamma(2^i \cdot 3) = i + 2$. It's possible to continue in this way but it's a bit tedious and the improvements to the lower bound are minor (only an additive rather than multiplicative improvement) and ultimately, because of the $\gamma$-recursion, aren't necessary. In particular we can generalize your argument to show that there are other forbidden values below $\frac{3}{4} 2^n$, for example the range between this and $\frac{5}{8} 2^n$ is also forbidden for $n \ge 3$.
We can also answer this question of yours:

Another interesting idea would be to write $k$ as $a \cdot b$, and work on $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$, it is true that $\gamma(k)=\gamma(a)+\gamma(b)$?

This is a tempting conjecture and I believed it for awhile but it's not true! The smallest counterexample is
$$\gamma(33) = 6 < \gamma(3) + \gamma(11) = 2 + 5 = 7$$
which comes from the fact that $33 = 2^5 + 1$, so it's more efficient in this case to subtract $1$ (the first case of the $\gamma$-recursion) than to factor (the second case). If this conjecture were true our sequence would be A064097, which is instead an upper bound and first differs at the above term. A064097 is itself quite a beautiful sequence with a recursive structure defined in terms of the prime factorization of $k$, then the prime factorization of the primes $p_i - 1$ that appear in the prime factorization $-1$, and so on.

It would also be interesting to consider the linear version of this question, where we take a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and a linear map $f : V \to V$ and count $f$-stable subspaces. I might post this as a question tomorrow.

Nice argument! I also thought about working on cycle-free functions, because I realized that the invariance didn't change if I "shortened" a longer cycle. It would be interesting to try to generate a number sequence of $\gamma(k)$, perhaps with a small program that generates all the possible functions on an increasing number of elements (perhaps with some smart tweaks, such as excluding cycles longer than 1)
